# Syntax highlighting not working in Vim when containerized in Docker

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-c++

I am running an instance of Vim in a Docker container, with configuration mostly taken from [here](https://github.com/danebulat/vim-cmake-boilerplate/blob/master/config/vimrc) (up untill `" Build debug and release targets...`)

As you can see on the pic, `clangd-completer` works correctly, as well as `nerdtree` and `tagbar`.

However, I don't seem to have any syntax highlighting in the main window (This is c++). I do not know Vim enough to understand what's wrong... (Also, I plan to use Vim with Docker only, if that's of any importance)

Any help?

**EDIT:** `:set term` returns `term=xterm-256color` and `:set t_Co` returns `t_Co=256`. I have pushed a github repo with the Dockerfile and related Vim config files.
https://github.com/gantsevdenis/vim-ide-cpp-tumbleweed

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Check if you have 256 colors enabled, if `:set t_Co?` returns 16 or less that might be the problem... Also check whether using `:set termguicolors` helps to fix the issue.

Comment: Also, is syntax and/or filetype detection on?

Comment: @filbranden `:set t_Co` returns 8. `:set termguicolors` doesn't have any effect

Comment: Does `:set t_Co=256` help fix the issue? What does `:set term?` return? Can you please [edit] the question to include your additional findings?

Comment: @filbranden That didn't to anything neither.. I have updated the question with a link to github repo (I have added ENV=xterm-256color variable, but that didn't help)

Comment: That is not what containers are made for. VMs? Yes. Containers? No.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that my .conf file was in a file path that vim's filetype.vim did not expect. I was able to get automatic syntax highlighting to work in vim 80 by editing the `filetype.vim` file in the following way.

`sudo vi /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim`

Find a line that ends with `setf apache`.

```
" Apache config file
au BufNewFile,BufRead .htaccess,*/etc/httpd/*.conf       setf apache
```

I opted to use Apache syntax highlighting for *any* .conf file, no matter its file path, by adding `,*.conf` to the list of paths on that line, like this:

```
" Apache config file
au BufNewFile,BufRead .htaccess,*/etc/httpd/*.conf,*.conf       setf apache
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You don't need to modify the `filetypes.vim` in the Vim runtimes directory... (The modification will get clobbered if/when the Vim package is upgraded.) Instead, you can create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/apache.vim` with the single line `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.conf set filetype=apache` for your override.

Comment: @filbranden - I like your suggestion but it didn't work to automatically syntax highlight my .conf file. I logged out and back in, too.

Comment: Ah, actually you need `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.conf set filetype=apache` for an override. (`set filetype=...` takes precedence over `setf`, so you should use it in an override to ensure it will be the one to take effect even though there are other existing rules for the same filename pattern.)

Comment: Still no joy. I tried replacing the line and adding it. Yes, I saved. I also logged off and back on. :)

Comment: Ah Sorry again, I got the extensions mixed up! The file in `ftdetect/` should have a `*.vim` extension. I edited my first comment to fix that up. Would you give that one last try?

Comment: That worked! Thank you, and Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy New Year!